# Indexed drawing with metal

Tags: ios, swift, metal, metalkit

I am trying to load a model (form .OBJ) and draw it to the screen on iOS with MetalKit. The problem is that instead of my model, I get some random polygons...
Here is the code that is tend to load the model(The code is based on a tutorial from *raywenderlich.com*:

```
        let allocator               = MTKMeshBufferAllocator(device: device)
        let vertexDescriptor        = MDLVertexDescriptor()
        let vertexLayout            = MDLVertexBufferLayout()
        vertexLayout.stride         = sizeof(Vertex)
        vertexDescriptor.layouts    = [vertexLayout]
        vertexDescriptor.attributes = [MDLVertexAttribute(name: MDLVertexAttributePosition, format: MDLVertexFormat.Float3, offset: 0, bufferIndex: 0),
                                       MDLVertexAttribute(name: MDLVertexAttributeColor, format: MDLVertexFormat.Float4, offset: sizeof(float3), bufferIndex: 0),
                                       MDLVertexAttribute(name: MDLVertexAttributeTextureCoordinate, format: MDLVertexFormat.Float2, offset: sizeof(float3)+sizeof(float4), bufferIndex: 0),
                                       MDLVertexAttribute(name: MDLVertexAttributeNormal, format: MDLVertexFormat.Float3, offset: sizeof(float3)+sizeof(float4)+sizeof(float2), bufferIndex: 0)]
        var error: NSError?
        let asset = MDLAsset(URL: path, vertexDescriptor: vertexDescriptor, bufferAllocator: allocator, preserveTopology: true, error: &error)
        if error != nil{
            print(error)
            return nil
        }

        let model = asset.objectAtIndex(0) as! MDLMesh
        let mesh  = try MTKMesh(mesh: model, device: device)
```

And here is my drawing method:

```
    func render(commandQueue: MTLCommandQueue, pipelineState: MTLRenderPipelineState,drawable: CAMetalDrawable,projectionMatrix: float4x4,modelViewMatrix: float4x4, clearColor: MTLClearColor){

    dispatch_semaphore_wait(bufferProvider.availibleResourcesSemaphore, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER)

    let renderPassDescriptor = MTLRenderPassDescriptor()
    renderPassDescriptor.colorAttachments[0].texture = drawable.texture
    renderPassDescriptor.colorAttachments[0].loadAction = .Clear
    renderPassDescriptor.colorAttachments[0].clearColor = clearColor
    renderPassDescriptor.colorAttachments[0].storeAction = .Store

    let commandBuffer = commandQueue.commandBuffer()
    commandBuffer.addCompletedHandler { (buffer) in
        dispatch_semaphore_signal(self.bufferProvider.availibleResourcesSemaphore)
    }

    let renderEncoder = commandBuffer.renderCommandEncoderWithDescriptor(renderPassDescriptor)
    renderEncoder.setCullMode(MTLCullMode.None)

    renderEncoder.setRenderPipelineState(pipelineState)
    renderEncoder.setVertexBuffer(vertexBuffer, offset: 0, atIndex: 0)
    renderEncoder.setFragmentTexture(texture, atIndex: 0)
    if let samplerState = samplerState{
        renderEncoder.setFragmentSamplerState(samplerState, atIndex: 0)
    }


    var nodeModelMatrix = self.modelMatrix()
    nodeModelMatrix.multiplyLeft(modelViewMatrix)
    uniformBuffer = bufferProvider.nextUniformsBuffer(projectionMatrix, modelViewMatrix: nodeModelMatrix, light: light)
    renderEncoder.setVertexBuffer(self.uniformBuffer, offset: 0, atIndex: 1)
    renderEncoder.setFragmentBuffer(uniformBuffer, offset: 0, atIndex: 1)
    if indexBuffer != nil{
        renderEncoder.drawIndexedPrimitives(.Triangle, indexCount: self.indexCount, indexType: self.indexType, indexBuffer: self.indexBuffer!, indexBufferOffset: 0)
    }else{
        renderEncoder.drawPrimitives(.Triangle, vertexStart: 0, vertexCount: vertexCount, instanceCount: vertexCount/3)
    }
    renderEncoder.endEncoding()

    commandBuffer.presentDrawable(drawable)
    commandBuffer.commit()
}
```

Here is my vertex shader:

```
struct VertexIn{
   packed_float3 position;
   packed_float4 color;
   packed_float2 texCoord;
   packed_float3 normal;
};

struct VertexOut{
    float4 position [[position]];
    float3 fragmentPosition;
    float4 color;
    float2 texCoord;
    float3 normal;
};

struct Light{
    packed_float3 color;
    float ambientIntensity;
    packed_float3 direction;
    float diffuseIntensity;
    float shininess;
    float specularIntensity;
};

struct Uniforms{
    float4x4 modelMatrix;
    float4x4 projectionMatrix;
    Light light;
};

vertex VertexOut basic_vertex(
                          const device VertexIn* vertex_array [[ buffer(0) ]],
                          const device Uniforms&  uniforms    [[ buffer(1) ]],
                          unsigned int vid [[ vertex_id ]]) {

   float4x4 mv_Matrix = uniforms.modelMatrix;
   float4x4 proj_Matrix = uniforms.projectionMatrix;

    VertexIn VertexIn = vertex_array[vid];

    VertexOut VertexOut;
    VertexOut.position = proj_Matrix * mv_Matrix * float4(VertexIn.position,1);
    VertexOut.fragmentPosition = (mv_Matrix * float4(VertexIn.position,1)).xyz;
    VertexOut.color = VertexIn.color;
    VertexOut.texCoord = VertexIn.texCoord;
    VertexOut.normal = (mv_Matrix * float4(VertexIn.normal, 0.0)).xyz;
    return VertexOut;
}
```

And here is how it looks like:

[link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l8qxM.jpg)

Actually I have an other class that is completely written by me to load models. It works fine, the problem is that it is not using indexing so f I try to load models that are more complex than a low-poly sphere, the GPU crashes... Anyways I tried to modify it to use indexing and I got the same result.. than I added hardcoded indices for testing and I got a really weird result. When I had 3 indices it drew a triangle, when I added 3 more, it drew the same triangle and after 3 more vertices it drew 2 triangles...

**Edit:**
Here is my `Vertex` structure:

```
struct Vertex:Equatable{
    var x,y,z: Float
    var r,g,b,a: Float
    var s,t: Float
    var nX,nY,nZ:Float

    func floatBuffer()->[Float]{
         return [x,y,z,r,g,b,a,s,t,nX,nY,nZ]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I see a couple of potential issues here.

1) Your vertex descriptor does not map exactly to your `Vertex` struct. The position variables (`x, y, z`) occupy 12 bytes, so the color variables start at an offset of 12 bytes. This matches the `packed_float3 position` field in your shader's `VertexIn` struct, but in the vertex descriptor you provide to Model I/O, you use `sizeof(Float3)`, which is 16, as the offset of the color attribute. Because you're packing the position field, you should use `sizeof(Float) * 3` for this value instead, and likewise in the subsequent offsets. I suspect this is the main cause of your problems.

More generally, it's a good idea to use `strideof` rather than `sizeof` to account for alignment, though--by chance--it wouldn't make a difference here.

2) Model I/O is allowed to use a single `MTLBuffer` to store both vertices and indices, so you should use the `offset` member of each `MTKMeshBuffer` when setting the vertex buffer or specifying the index buffer in each draw call, rather than assuming the offsets to be 0.

Comment: Hey thanks :) Your first point solved the problem. The second did nothing (At least I can not see.) But I am assuming that you know it better so I leave it there :) 
One more question. I see that the textures appear weird. I think it is because I am using only one texel per vertex and throw away the other (if ther is more). Can you give me any suggestions to solve this? Thx

Comment: Update: I've found that I can ask for `MDLVertexAttributeTextureCoordinate`  attribute of `MDLMesh`. Than I could pass it to the shader to use. But I have to problems. 1) How can I convert it to a buffer? I know how to convert c type arrays to swift arrays and than to `MTLBuffers` but I can not find the length of the attribute. 2) How can I know which `texel` do I need in the shader.

Comment: Excellent questions, but they're out of scope for me to answer in the comments--can you post another question regarding texturing?

Comment: Of course :) [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39427384/texture-coordinates-and-normals-with-indexed-drawing-metal)